# What is the Linux file dirty page write back order

Tags: linux, files

In Linux, for a single file what is the dirty page write back(to disk) order? Is it from beginning to end or out of order ?

Scenario 1 : without overwrite

A file(in disk) is created and large amount of data is written (sequentially) quickly. Now I presume these would be in multiple page caches. When writing back the dirty pages is pages written back in order?

e.g. Say server shutdowns before file write completion.

Now after reboot can we have the disk file in below state

> |--correct data --|---data unset/garbage--|--correct data--|

i.e. I understand last set of bytes in file can be incomplete, but can data in mid be incomplete

Scenario 2 : with overwrite (attempt to use file similar to a circular/ring buffer)

1. File created, data written, after reaching a max size, "fsync"
   called (i.e. data+meta data synchronized).
2. Now, file pointer is
   moved to the beginning of the file and data written sequentially.
   (No fsync done)

Now due to a server shutdown can we have the disk file in below state after reboot

> ```
> |--Newly written data--|--Old data--|--New data--|...
> ```

i.e. for new data, some pages were written to disk out of order

OR

Can I assume it is always

> |--Newly written data--|----Newly written data--|--Old data--|

i.e. old data and new data will not mix-up (if present old data would only be at the end of file)